# Woocommerce hook: How to add content inside the feature products on home page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the custom message inside the woocommerce website "Featured Product" section.
Like content goes inside the red box:
[image]

I've found the hook like below but it does not have any effect:

```
add_action('storefront_homepage_after_featured_products_title','homepage',15);

function homepage() {
    echo "test";
}
```

I also try below code but that only display message under catalogue page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'catalogue_message', 15);

function catalogue_message() {
    global $product;
    
    $item_cost = $product->get_price();
    if($item_cost != '') {
        echo "TEST";    
    }
}
```

So not sure what's the name of woocommerce hook that can add the custom message on home page - Featured Product section.

Can anyone please let me know the name of the hook.

Thanks:)

Comment: I also tried using a hook from the Shop Loop and it only worked on my catalog and "shop" page, but wouldn't work on my homepage.  If you found an answer to this, can you please post a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to add html after price in featured product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'theme_add_description_after_or_after_price', 2, 10 );

function theme_add_description_after_or_after_price($price, $product){
    $description = ($product->is_featured()) ? 'Your HTML or text' : '';
    return $price . $description  ;
}
```